# i started working on a discord bot with discordjs

Tags: javascript, express, discord.js

i started working on a discord bot with discordjs and i wanted to get some data from the steam api and then to embed it

```
    const gtaUrl = 'https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetNumberOfCurrentPlayers/v1/?key=KEY&format=json&appid=271590'
let gtaData ='';
request(gtaUrl,function(err,res,body){

    if(!err&&res.statusCode<400){
        gtaData +=body;
        }
})
const exampleEmbed =  new MessageEmbed()
.setColor('#0099ff')
.setTitle('Showing concurrent player numbers for some games')
.setDescription('the game')
.setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/FNviTdG.jpeg')
.addFields(
    { name: 'tf2 ', value: gtaData },
)
.addField('Inline field title', 'Some value here', true)
.setImage('https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png')
.setTimestamp()
message.channel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
```

[the request and the embeding code ]
but  when i run the code it crashed and says that the embded fields are empty i think i know what the problem is when i send the request it takes time for the data to arrive and the code moves on so the strings stay empty but i dont really know what to do with is i still dont fully understand the whole js thing and im using express for the request part;
the terminal error:

if (!allowEmpty && data.length === 0) throw new error(errorMessage);
RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values must be non-empty strings.
at Util.verifyString (D:\Code\discordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\Util.js:428:49)
at MessageEmbed.normalizeField (D:\Code\discordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:544:19)
at D:\Code\discordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:565:14
at Array.map ()
at MessageEmbed.normalizeFields (D:\Code\discordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:564:8)
at MessageEmbed.addFields (D:\Code\discordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:328:42)
at steamStatus (D:\Code\discordBot\src\bot.js:112:3)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
[Symbol(code)]: 'EMBED_FIELD_VALUE'
}

Comment: me having a grammatical error is not me not showing "professional courtesy"  I speak 3 languages (english as the third)  plus i have dyslexia,  you dont have to be rude about it @isherwood

Answer (score 0):

You can just move your code inside request's callback

for example:

```
const gtaUrl =
  "https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetNumberOfCurrentPlayers/v1/?key=KEY&format=json&appid=271590";
let gtaData = "";
request(gtaUrl, function (err, res, body) {
  if (!err && res.statusCode < 400) {
    gtaData += body;

    const exampleEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setColor("#0099ff")
      .setTitle("Showing concurrent player numbers for some games")
      .setDescription("the game")
      .setThumbnail("https://i.imgur.com/FNviTdG.jpeg")
      .addFields({ name: "tf2 ", value: gtaData })
      .addField("Inline field title", "Some value here", true)
      .setImage("https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png")
      .setTimestamp();
  }
});
```

Another way to do this is with [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) or a library like [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)

Here's an example with Axios

```
const gtaUrl =
    "https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetNumberOfCurrentPlayers/v1/?key=KEY&format=json&appid=271590";
  
const response = await axios.get(gtaUrl);
gtaData = JSON.stringify(response.data);

const exampleEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("#0099ff")
    .setTitle("Showing concurrent player numbers for some games")
    .setDescription("the game")
    .setThumbnail("https://i.imgur.com/FNviTdG.jpeg")
    .addFields({ name: "tf2 ", value: gtaData })
    .addField("Inline field title", "Some value here", true)
    .setImage("https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png")
    .setTimestamp();
```

Comment: it wont work beacuse i have more then one request and i want to embed them to the same message 
but thanks you will read about the Pomise and Ferch

Comment: @ConstantineJon I updated my solution with one that will probably work for your use case